# What is the intuitive meaning of selecting high or low Q value in Kalman filter?

Tags: discrete-signals, kalman-filters

I am working on experimental data, where I need to choose Q in Kalman filter. How to intuitively understand:

1. What does selecting low value of Q indicates in Kalman filter?
2. What does selecting high value of Q indicates in Kalman filter?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245167/kalman-filter-in-computer-vision-the-choice-of-q-and-r-noise-covariances#:~:text=Q%20is%20a%20measure%20of,measurements%20you%20could%20estimate%20Q.

Answer (score 1):

Your first intuition shouldn't be an intuition at all -- if you're *selecting* a $\mathbf Q$, then you're not building a *real* Kalman filter!

A "true" Kalman filter is constructed with an accurate model of the system *including precise knowledge about the process and measurement noise*.

But -- most of the time, when someone says they're using a "Kalman filter" they mean that they're making an informed guess about the structure of a system, then they're tuning it by guess and by gosh by twiddling the values of the process noise covariance and the measurement covariance.

(Note that you can't ignore the $\mathbf R$ matrix here -- the actual Kalman gain at each step ends up depending on the ratio of $\mathbf P$ and $\mathbf Q$ vs. $\mathbf R$.  Once the filter has settled to steady state, it just depends on $\mathbf Q$ vs. $\mathbf R$).

For the case of a $\mathbf Q$ that is only non-zero on the diagonals, selecting a low value of some $q_{n, n}$ means that the corresponding state value does not get rapidly corrupted by noise.  A high value means the opposite.  For a $\mathbf Q$ that's not just a diagonal matrix, a small eigenvalue means certainty in the corresponding direction of the $\mathbf x$ vector, while a larger one means less certainty.

In general, what this means is that a large eigenvalue in the $\mathbf Q$ matrix means that the corresponding state estimate will follow measurements more closely (assuming small values in the bits of the $\mathbf R$ matrix that influences those states).  Small eigenvalues means that the state will respond more slowly to measurements.